# Troubles with simple mocking using RhinoMocks .NET

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

I am trying to experiment with RhinoMocks, where I have to say I am a newbie and probably I don't get some obvious thing here. What I'm doing is something like :

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void SaveResponsibleUserFromChangeset()
    {
        var action = mocks.StrictMock<GenomeAction>();
        var changeset = new ActionChangeset();

        changeset.ResponsibleUser = new ChangeableProperty<UserIdentity>("Administrator") {IsChanged = true};
        changeset.MarkAll(true);

        using(mocks.Record())
        {
            Expect.Call(action.ResponsibleUser).SetPropertyAndIgnoreArgument();
        }

        using(mocks.Playback())
        {
            var persistor = new ActionPersistor(new MockIdentityResolver());
            persistor.SaveActionChanges(changeset, action);
        }

        action.VerifyAllExpectations();
    }

    private class MockIdentityResolver : IIdentityResolver
    {
        public GenomeUser GetUser(UserIdentity identity)
        {
            var user = mocks.DynamicMock<GenomeUser>();
            user.Username = identity.Username;
            return user;
        }
    }
```

The intention is to have a very simple test which checks whether the `SaveActionChanges` method sets the `ResponsibleUser` property. As a part of this, it needs to resolve the user identity using the resolver, for which I have provided a mock implementation. Unfortunately, it seems I can't just return back another mock within the Playback mode, because it says (on the closing bracket of the second using) that *The action is invalid when the object (of type GenomeUser) is in record state*.

Any ideas of what is causing the trouble and how to overcome it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to create you `new MockIdentityResolver()` outside the `mocks.Playback()`.

```
[TestMethod]
public void SaveResponsibleUserFromChangeset()
{
    var action = mocks.StrictMock<GenomeAction>();
    var changeset = new ActionChangeset();
    var identityResolver;
    changeset.ResponsibleUser = new ChangeableProperty<UserIdentity>("Administrator") {IsChanged = true};
    changeset.MarkAll(true);

    using(mocks.Record())
    {
        Expect.Call(action.ResponsibleUser).SetPropertyAndIgnoreArgument();
        identityResolver = new MockIdentityResolver()
    }

    using(mocks.Playback())
    {
        var persistor = new ActionPersistor(identityResolver);
        persistor.SaveActionChanges(changeset, action);
    }

    action.VerifyAllExpectations();
}

private class MockIdentityResolver : IIdentityResolver
{
    public GenomeUser GetUser(UserIdentity identity)
    {
        var user = mocks.DynamicMock<GenomeUser>();
        user.Username = identity.Username;
        return user;
    }
}
```

you should look at using the [AAA syntax](http://www.ayende.com/Wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx), it seems to be generally accepted that it's a clearer way of using stuff.

Comment: I have used your advice and rewritten the thing completely in AAA syntax way and now it's working like charm. Thanks ;)

Comment: Another +1 from me for the AAA syntax; the Rhino Mocks author, Oren Eini, has mentioned the next version of his framework will do away with the Record/Playback syntax, and offer only the AAA syntax.